# Inline jinja2 if condition in Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I can't run the inline elif jinja statement from Ansible playbook. I've play as shown below

vm_number is dynamically generated, there is vars file with has the values of each vm(for eg: "PARAMS_vm_1").

PARAMS_vm_1:
 - IP
 - name
 - fqdn
 - os
 - location

**Condition:**
< 5 error
= 5 append a value to the list
anything else just set the value of `PARAMS_vm_1` to a `get_vmdata`

```
- name: set vm name
  set_fact:
    vmname: "vm_{{ vm_number }}"
 - name: set PARAMS_vmname
   set_fact:
     PARAMS_vmname: "PARAMS_{{ vmname }}"
 - name: get get_vmdata
   set_fact:
     get_vmdata: "{{ error if ((lookup('vars', PARAMS_vmname)) | length < 5) elif ((lookup('vars', PARAMS_vmname)) | length = 5) (lookup('vars', PARAMS_vmname)) + none else (lookup('vars', SUBTOPO_PARAMS_simname)) }}"
```

If I use only if else statement - it's working fine.

If I included the `elif` condition it's showing the following error -`"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token 'end of print statement', got 'elif'.`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the `if-elif-else-endif` jinja statement works for me.

You need to obviously make changes to this command but make sure you use quotes `"` or `'` wherever needed.

```
"{% if <your condition> %}<your command or message>{% elif <your condition> %}<your command or message>{% else <your condition> %}<your command or message>{% endif %}"
```